# Angular WithCredentials not working for POST, PUT

Tags: .net, angular, cors, httpclient

I'm working on an Angular site with:

• .Net Framework server on localhost/test

• client on localhost:4200

I've got cookie authentication working, and my GET requests are working fine.

```
   this.httpClient.get<Test>('dummyUrl', { withCredentials: true });
```

In my web.config for the server I have the following.

```
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true"/>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:4200" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*" />
```

---

Given this setup I'd expect the same to work for PUT and POST requests.

```
    this.httpClient.put('dummyUrl', this.payload, { withCredentials: true });
```

I get a 401 Unauthorized from this.

---

**My Investigation**

The request method I see made is OPTIONS, which tells me that this is failing on the pre-flight, and that this issue relates to CORS rather than Angular. I've been unable to work out what I'm missing.

I'd be grateful for any guidance.

Comment: where you able to solve the problem, I am facing exactly the same one

Answer (score 4):

if you are using in asp net core api with angular on front end, then in web api, start up  setting (under configure method),

set following setting

```
        app.UseCors(options =>
        {
            options.SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true);
            //options.AllowAnyOrigin();
            options.AllowAnyHeader();
            options.AllowAnyMethod();
            options.AllowCredentials();   <-- This one is important
        });
```

and it should work.

Comment: options.AllowCredentials() is needed for http post to work and it fixed the CORS issue

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code.

```
import { RequestOptions, Headers } from '@angular/http';

let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, withCredentials: true });

this.httpClient.put('dummyUrl', this.payload, options);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
RequestOptions has been deprecated, so I feel I should avoid it.
In the interests of debugging I tried it anyway and got the same 401 behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar problems too, even with `{withCredentials: true}` on my POST requests.

In my Spring Boot server's code, where it deals with CORS, I had the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header set to `*`. I changed `*` to `http://localhost:4200`, where my Angular app was being served from.

Things worked fine after that. Hope this helps someone.